# Android SDK Build Tools version (23.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (27.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.2

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I have a problem with a project that I take in collage.
After I open up the project I get this error:

> "The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (23.0.3) is ignored, as
>   it is below the minimum supported version (27.0.3) for Android Gradle
>   Plugin 3.1.2."

Screenshot of message:

[image: the error in circle]

I have tried changing the `buildToolsVersion` but nothing happens.
I'm still new so cry if the question is not ok something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple. Simply install the appropriate SDK version.

1. Find this button:

[image: SDK Manager]

2. Install the version you want / need:

[image: Install]

3. Code!

Let me know how it turned out.

And please try to be more correct with your english.

---

UPDATE:

Go to your build.gradle (Module: app) and check if these match:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    ...

    defaultConfig {

        ...

        minSdkVersion 19

        ...
```

They should point to the same main version.
The "minSdkVersion" should be below the "buildToolsVersion", not the other way around.

Comment: ok first of all sry about the english sec : this is not the problem i install all sdk an nuthing.

Comment: No problem. We've all been there ;) I updated my answer. Check it out.

Comment: Don't take it the wrong way. I only mentioned your english because you have words like "thet", "collage" or "nuthing happans" which are easily corrected by Google Translate. You don't need to be a master english speaker, but we do need to understand what you write so we can help you.